# Input the results of a function into an equation automatically

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have written the following code:

```
vel;
all;

for n = 1:482136
    c = all((n+1):(n+25));
    y(n) = rmse(vel,c);

end

[r,d] = sort(y);
```

"vel" and "all" are variables. "vel" has 25 data points and "all" has over 480,000. this code is calculating the rmse between the two variables by looping over 25 data points. it then sorts by the lowest rmse and which data point from "all" corresponds to it. next, i want the code to automatically input the first 10 results corresponding to the lowest rmses into the equation c = all((n+1):(n+25)). is it possible to do this? i can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You run this code, then you get the sorted rmses and then you want to plug the 10 lowest back into the for-loop?

Comment: + `all` is a matlab function and should not be used as a variable.